# How to select / highlight an item in listview without touching it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

On click on next button, the list should highlight/select next item in the listview.
How can i achieve it without actually touching the list item directly on the screen?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[ListView.setSelection(int pos)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29)** will help you to achieve this.

Comment: I have tried that, though I am able to get the vales of list using it. Not able to achieve my requirement.
Is there any way to highlight the same item in list ?

Comment: Your solution doesn't highlight the item

Answer (score 0):

on next click u can change the background of the respective item and store the position for further work.this will be act as selected items